# Error somehow related to using the footer of library mpdf

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, mpdf

I'm using CodeIgniter with the mpdf library to create pdf files.

It works just fine until I try to add a footer.
Every time I add the footer, whenever I try to open the generated file I get this error:

> File Does Not Begin With '%PDF-' Local\EWH-6160-0

If I skip the footer, it works fine, I don't understand how the error is related to the footer.

This is the controller that creates the pdf:

```
    public function print_beneficiaries($cod){

    $mpdf = new mPDF( 'utf-8', 'A3' );

    $name = $this->natural_md->client_name($cod);
    $account = $this->formats->retrieve_account($cod); 
    $data = $this->formats->beneficiaries( $cod );
    $date = $this->formats->mult_contract( $cod );
    $list = array();

    if($data > 0){
        $i = 1;
        foreach ( $data as $benef ){
            array_push( $list, array(
                    'cod' => $cod,
                    'id_beneficiary' => $benef['id_beneficiary'],
                    'name' => $benef['beneficiary_name'],
                    'relationship' => $benef['relationship'],
                    'benef_percentage' => $benef['benef_percentage'],
                    'identification' => $benef['identification'],
                    'identification_type' => $benef['identification_type'],
                    'address' => $benef['address'],
                    'email' => $benef['email'],
                    'telephone' => $benef['telephone'],
                    'celphone' => $benef['celphone'],
                    'letter' => $this->utilities->get_letter($i) 
            ) );

            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }
    else
        $list = array();

    $mpdf->SetFooter("{PAGENO}/{nb}");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($this->load->view( 'pdf/pn_beneficiaries', array(
            'list' => $list,
            'account_name' => ucwords($name[0]['names']),
            'account_id' => $account == null ? 0 : $account->id,
            'account' => $account == '' ? 0 :$cuenta->account_name, 
            'day' =>    sprintf('%02d', $date[0]['day']),
            'month' =>  sprintf('%02d', $date[0]['month']),
            'year' =>   $date[0]['year'],               
    ), true ) );
    $mpdf->Output("Beneficiaries - ".$cod.".pdf", "I");

}
```

The view from which the controller retrieves the data is this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Beneficiaries</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?
     >/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?
     >/assets/css/font.css" />
     <style>
      body{
          color: #0a0a0a;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
      }
      .foot{
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           left: 900px;
           width: 100%;
           float: right;
       }
      .espacio{
          margin-top: 4px;
          width: 900px;
      }
      .espacio h3{
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: 700;
      }
      .per{
          font-size: 14px;
          text-align: justify;
      }
      table{
         font-size: 16px;
      }
      th{
          padding:4px;
          text-align: center;
      }
      table.border td{
          border: solid 2px #B1B1B1;
      }
      td{
          padding:4px;
      }
      u{
          height: 2px;
      }
      .logo{
          text-align: center;
      }
      @media print {
          #with_print {
              display: none;
          }
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="container logo">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/img/logo-inver-
             new.jpg" width="180px">
       </div>
      </div>
     </header>
     <div class="container espacio" >
      <h3>
         Beneficiary designation
      </h3>
      <div class="espacio per">
         <p>
           some text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="container">
         <table border="1" class="border">
           <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style=" background-color: #30859B; color: #fff;  
            font-size: 16px; margin: 5px;">Fecha</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style=" font-size: 16px;"><?php echo $day; ?></td>
               <td style=" font-size: 16px;"><?php echo $month; ?></td>
               <td style=" font-size: 16px;"><?php echo $year; ?></td>                    
           </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <?php $cont = 0; $filas=count($list);?>
          <?php foreach ($list as $row):?>
              <div class="container">
               <table border="1" align="center" class="border">
                <tr>
                 <td colspan="2"  style=" background-color: #30859B; color: 
                 #fff;">Beneficiario <?php echo $row['letter']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">Nombre del Beneficiario: <span style="font-
                 size: 18px; font-style: italic; color: 
                 #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $row['name']; ?> </span> 
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td  style="width: 500px;">Parentesco:  <span style="font-
                 size: 18px; font-style: italic; color: 
                 #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo $row['relationship']; ?>
                 </span> </td>
                 <td  style="width: 500px;">% del Beneficiario:  <span 
                 style="font-size: 18px; font-style: italic; color: 
                 #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;
                    <?php 
                      if(!empty($row['benef_percentage']))
                      {echo $row['benef_percentage'].' %';} 
                      ?></span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>No. Identificación: <span style="font-size: 18px; font-
                 style: italic; color: #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo 
                 $row['identification']; ?></span> </td>
                 <td>Tipo de Identificación:  <span style="font-size: 18px; 
                 font-style: italic; color: #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo 
                 $row['identification_type']; ?> </span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">Dirección del Beneficiario: <span 
                 style="font-size: 18px; font-style: italic; color: 
                 #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp; <?php echo $row['address']; ?>
                 </span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">Correo Electrónico: <span style="font-size: 
                 18px; font-style: italic; color: #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp; <?
                 php echo $row['email']; ?></span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>Teléfono Domicilio: <span style="font-size: 18px; font-
                 style: italic; color: #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo 
                 $row['telephone']; ?></span> </td>
                 <td>Teléfono Celular: <span style="font-size: 18px; font-
                 style: italic; color: #2b2b2b;">&emsp;&emsp;<?php echo 
                 $row['celphone']; ?> </span> </td>
                </tr>
               </table>
              </div>
              <?php $cont++;
                  if ($cont%5==0 && $filas>5) {
                      echo '
                      <pagebreak>  
                      ';
                  }
               ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <table style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre de la cuenta: <?php echo $filas ?></td>
                <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #000; width: 100%"><?php 
                  if (isset($account) && ($account!='')) {
                        echo $account;
                  }else{
                    echo $account_name;
                  }
                ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 espacio">
        <p style="text-align: justify;"><span style=" font-weight: 
        bold;">Nota:</span>Other text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <tr >
                <td  style="width: 100px;"></td>
                <td style="border-top: solid 1px #000; width: 250px; text-
                align: center; font-size: 16px;" >Firma del Cliente</td>
                <td  style="width: 100px;"></td>
                <td style="border-top: solid 1px #000; ; width: 350px; text-
                align: center; font-size: 16px;" >Firma del 
                Cliente<br>Cuenta Mancomunada</td>
                <td  style="width: 100px;"></td>
                <td style="border-top: solid 1px #000;width: 290px; text-
                align: center; font-size: 16px;">
                        Firma del Funcionario IPB
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: you are missing `'` in `'address => $benef['address'],`. replace it with `'address' => $benef['address'],`.

Comment: If the message tells you that the file does not begin with [...], then the very first thing you should do is go and open that file in a text editor, to see what it _actually_ contains. Pretty sure that would in this case be a PHP error message.

Comment: For some reason, when i copied my code for the post i missed the ' . In my actual code i do have it tho, so i still have the error and it's driving me maaaaad haha.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a similar post.  I opened the file on word and the error was: **preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead** on the mpdf.php file line 12492.  I searched for the solution, just change the original code: `$hd = preg_replace('/\{DATE\s+(.*?)\}/e',"date('\\1')",$hd);`  to this: `$hd = preg_replace_callback('/\{DATE\s+(.*?)\}/m', function($m){ return date($m[1]);},$hd);`